# Eclipse not showing javadocs for jdk10

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I have JDK 10 and eclipse Photon installed on my windows 10 system.
Both of them are working fine and eclipse is very well compiling my Java apps and running them as well.

But when I roll-over my cursor on syntax, then it is not showing its description.
It says :
This element has no attached source and the Javadoc could not be found in the attached Javadoc.

for every element. I could not find anything useful on the google and also the similar post from StackOverFlow is old about jdk 7.

Now, since the jdk folder doesnt have JRE anymore, the eclipse is linked to the jre folder outside the jdk. However, I tried all jars in lib of jdk and still no luck.

What is the problem?

Comment: When you added the JRE under Windows > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs you should have added the JDK directory, probably `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2`

Comment: What JRE folder outside of the JDK?

Comment: Can you update your post with a screen shot of your installed JREs? To do that, navigate to  **Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs**. Ensure that each column in your screen shot is wide enough to display all the data.